# find/tar combination to backup certain files at one level, and all files in one subdirectory

Tags: bash, backup, tar, find

Our server's directory structure is like this

- /home/site1/public_html
- /home/site1/logs
- /home/site1/cgi-bin
- etc...(it's the standard when using virtualmin)

What I want to schedule backups for is the public_html directories + some files at the site1/ level (there are often some handy scripts written in those levels, but also there are inevitably a bunch of bloat files there too like temp db dumps that I don't want filling up the backup server every job)

Here's what I would like to do if possible (from /home/):

```
tar -cz --include="*.sh" --include="*.php" --include="public_html/*" ./site1/ | ssh backupserver ...
```

But, tar doesn't have an include option, only exclude.

I've tried

```
find ./site1/ -type f -name "*.sh" -or -name "*.php" -or -wholename "./site1/public_html/*" | xargs tar -cz | ssh backupserver ...
```

But that doesn't work either because xargs breaks a large list of files into chunks, causing every restart of the tar -c command to overwrite the previous file (and if I don't use xargs, then there is an error for the list being too long).

I can't use the -r option to append to the backup because 1) it doesn't work on compressed archives and 2) I don't think that could work across ssh anyway.

The only solution I can think of is to break it into steps creating a temporary tar file locally (one to tar ./site1/public_html/ and another to append ./site1/*.[sh|php]), then zipping, then ssh, then delete the local file.  But that seems almost ridiculous on linux.

Is there some format to the tar command that I can use that I'm missing?

Comment: Try using the `-T -` option to tar with find instead of using xargs. This will cause tar to read its list of files from stdin, which may be what you want.

Comment: Yes!  `find ./site1/ -type f [-name/-wholename/-path filters] | tar -cz -T -| ssh ...`

Answer (score 1):

`globstar` to the rescue?

```
shopt -s globstar
tar -cz archive.tar.gz file1 file2 subdir/**
```

Answer (score 0):

`pax`, this is your time to shine!

```
find ./site1/ \( -path "./site1/public_html" -prune -o -name "*.sh" -o -name "*.php" \) -print |
    pax -x ustar -wf archive.tar
```

Or when you have a `find` and `pax` that both support NUL delimited data:

```
find ./site1/ \( -path "./site1/public_html" -prune -o -name "*.sh" -o -name "*.php" \) -print0 |
    pax -x ustar -0wf archive.tar
```